# If nodejs-mongoose form hosted, then how to store form data to db without running mongod

Tags: html, css, node.js, mongodb, express

How to store the form data into mongodb, while it is running on server and mongod is not running even in background. Is it possible to do that?

Im Expecting to get form data stored into db, even if I give Server hosted url to any non IT friend. Then also he must be able to store his form data successfully to the database without running any instance of mongod. Will that possible?

Comment: Hi, before trying to code that, you must undesrtand all the mechanisms of a client/server situation